# Android Studion does not launch App after Installation (app run is not working)

Tags: android

After upgrading Android Studio to Girafee, I configured something in my Audriod Studio Setting.
After that whenever I install app, it says Install successfull but does not launch App.
I have to click my app to run everytime just after installed . This situation is same on physical device and emulator.

And I tried to find out which parameters I changed, but I could not find what I've changed.
How I can launch app just after installation automatically as I used to?

After then, I can not start debug also, it says wait for connection (I think because app cannot be launched, it is waiting ...) and then gone.

One more thing, is there any way to hide device image mirroring on my stuio screen?

Following is my current version information from About popup screen.

```
    Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996, built on June 29, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 8
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.instant.shutdown=false
    ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.intellij.marketplace (223.8836.56)
    dev.polek.adbwifi (1.2.5)
    indent-rainbow.indent-rainbow (2.1.0)
    com.github.ArtsiomCh.NestedBracketsColorer (0.7.1)
    org.01pawn.rainbow-variable (1.3)
```